# Why did MVVMLight's RelayCommand use WeakAction

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, garbage-collection, mvvm-light

I noticed that `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf.RelayCommand<T>` using `WeakAction<T>`.

this design consideration was surprising to me and I did a little further investigation.
while browsing the web, I came across [this blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dinazil/2015/01/16/relaycommands-weakfuncs/) which strengthen my suspicion, but did not answer my original question as to "Why?"

Why would GalaSoft intentionally use `WeakAction` instead of plain `Action` allow the functions to get Garbage Collected?

Thank you.

Comment: Why does `WeakAction<T>` exist at all? Because there are always developers thinking that weak listeners (or similar constructs) were a good idea. Some of them happen to design libraries…

Answer (score 3):

> Why would GalaSoft intentionally use `WeakAction` instead of plain `Action` allow the functions to get Garbage Collected?

Most probably to prevent the commands(s) from keeping the owner(s) of the action(s) alive and cause memory leaks in an `MvvmLight` application.

Using a `WeakAction<T>`, the owner is still eligible for garbage collection despite the fact the command may be not as there is no strong reference between the command and the owner of the action.

Comment: I Understand how the mechanism work, but i didn't understand the design consideration. 
What is the scenario which can cause the Leak ? 
if the command is not referenced, then it's action will be collected too...

Comment: The scenario that may cause a leak is when the command has a lifetime that exceeds the lifetime of the owner of the action.

Comment: What do you mean by _the owner(s) of the action(s)_?

Answer (score -1):

This to create Weak Reference with the `Action`'s owner. As that the owner `Action` can be garbage collected at any time.

**Ref.**

http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/aac8fdf1-873d-4e6b-ce31-af2dcf02d1d0.htm
https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Helpers/WeakAction.cs

Comment: This state what a weakAction Is... i was askink Why was it used there... alloweing action methods to be GC.

Comment: @TomerW Yes. My understanding is also the same; as per the documentation(mvvmlight.net).

Comment: @dhilmathy No, your understanding is not the same. He's asking for *why* they chose to use a `WeakAction` in the implementation of `RelayCommand`, not what `WeakAction` does. Also, the first link is dead